# Angular 4 - count rate from reviews

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating review form with firebase and angular 4, I have problem with counting length of added reviews and sum of this ratings. My form is pushing to a list of objects recently added reviews. I don't know how to iterate and count this ratings into one variable and devide by reviews.length.

[image]

**review.component.ts**

```
export class ProductReviewsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("product") product: Product;
  currentRate = 8;
  review = {};
  reviews = {};
  description;
  product$;
  number = [];

  constructor(private reviewService: ReviewsService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.product$ = await this.reviewService.getReview(this.product.$key);
    this.number = [];
    console.log(this.number);
  }

  addReview() {
    let review = {
        rate: this.currentRate,
        description: this.review
    }

    this.reviewService.saveReview(this.product.$key, review);
  }
}
```

html

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
    <textarea #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="review.description" name="description" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dodaj opis..."
      required></textarea>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="description.touched && description.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="description.errors.required">Name is required</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <button (click)="addReview()" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj opinię</button>

  <div *ngFor="let review of product$ | async">
    {{ review.rate }} {{ review.description.description }}
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Ok i did that, i will add answer tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[firebase.database.DataSnapshot forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

Seems to me like you could simply iterate over the response `snapshot` pushing the key:value pair into an array (if key matches whatever key you want). `.then` you've got your array.length and you've got your numbers/data to work with.

> ```
> // Assume we have the following data in the Database:
> {
>   "users": {
>     "ada": {
>       "first": "Ada",
>       "last": "Lovelace"
>     },
>     "alan": {
>       "first": "Alan",
>       "last": "Turing"
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> // Loop through users in order with the forEach() method. The callback
> // provided to forEach() will be called synchronously with a DataSnapshot
> // for each child:
> var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
> query.once("value")
>   .then(function(snapshot) {
>     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
>       // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
>       var key = childSnapshot.key;
>       // childData will be the actual contents of the child
>       var childData = childSnapshot.val();
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: I did this yesterday in some other way, but this works too thank you for answer :)